# Why can't i make 1 hour timeout message?

Tags: c#, error-handling, raspberry-pi, visual-studio-2019, iot

i have programmed a sensor that used for measure the water content in the plant, the sensor will running until about 5 minutes if it didnt used it will stop and will show and error message

```
mySerialPort.ReadTimeout = 60* 1000 * 5;

private void button_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Sensor_input_Helper.DeleteBatch(Sensor_input_Helper.GetLocalIPAddress());
duration_start = DateTime.Now;
bool check_connect_result = false;
try
{
check_connect_result = check_connection_sensor();
}
...
catch (TimeoutException ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(this, "Error 011");
//bool error = true;
next_action_button(true);
Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

but if i change it to 60 ( 1 hour ), the sensor didnt stop and the error message didnt appear.
i couldnt find whats is wrong, please help.

Comment: Try catching all exceptions.

Comment: Unrelated: For readablity, I'd recommend to do `mySerialPort.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds;`